# How can I handle precision for floating-point in my custom printf()-like function such as: %.2f?

Tags: c, printf

I am attempting to create a custom function similar to printf(), but I'm encountering an error when printing floating-point numbers with precision. The issue arises when I try to handle the precision part of the format specifier, such as %.2f. How can I implement the precision handling for floating-point numbers in my custom printf()-like function?

**main function:**
has the text I'm trying to print:

```
int main(void)
{
    fprint("first I fixed the integer call u can see here I can print an integer %d, I also can print a character: %c and a string: %s, and lastly I can print a float value like: %.2f\n", 567, 'a', "Hey", 65.13);
    fprint("I can print this too: %%, without a problem\n");
    return (0);
}
```

**my custome printf()-like function:**

```
void fprint(char *str, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int length = strlen(str);
    char pr = '%';
    char *s_holder, c_holder;

    va_start(args, str);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
        if (str[i] != '%')
    {
        write(1, &str[i], 1);
    }
    else if (str[i] == '%')
    {
        switch (str[i+1]){
            case 'd':
                print_integer(va_arg(args, int));
                i += 1;
                break;
            case 'c':
                c_holder = va_arg(args, int);
                write(1, &c_holder, 1);
                i += 1;
                break;
            case 's':
                s_holder = va_arg(args, char *);
                write(1, s_holder, strlen(s_holder));
                i += 1;
                break;
            case 'f':
                print_double(va_arg(args, double));
                i += 1;
                break;
            case '.':
                if (str[i + 2] >= '0' && str[i + 2] <= '9')
                {
                    print_double2(va_arg(args, double), str[i + 2]);
                    i += 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    write(1, &str[i], 1);
                }
                break;
            default:
                write(1, &str[i], 1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**the function that handle the floating-point:**

```
void print_double2(int num, char cprecision)
{
    int precision = atoi(cprecision);

    //handling the negative numbers
    if (num < 0)
    {
        write(1, "-", 1);
        num = -num;
    }

    //separating the integer part from the fractional part
    int int_part = (int)num;
    double fract_part = num - int_part;
    
    int int_fract;
    char digit;

    //printing the integer part of the double number with the print_integer function
    print_integer(int_part);

    write(1, ".", 1);

    //printing the fraction part
    while (fract_part > 0 && precision > 0)
    {
        fract_part *= 10;
        int_fract = (int)fract_part; //getting the int part after mult by 10
        digit = '0' + (int_fract % 10);
        write(1, &digit, 1); //printing the integer part
        fract_part -= int_fract; //removing the integer part to start the process again
        precision--; //decrementing the precision until it get to 0.
    }
}
```

I really don't know what to do, I'm still a beginner, I just started to learn a month ago.
I tried to use chatgpt but it didn't help.

Comment: There are many `printf` implementations available as source, all over the Internet. You can try and find one of those to see how they handle it? It's probably not trivial, so why do you need to create your own function instead of using an existing implementation? What is the actual problem that's supposed to solve?

Comment: Case in point: `atoi(cprecision)`... Unless you have your own non-standard `atoi` function which only takes a single character to convert to a number, it should be taking a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string. And no matter if you use the standard function or your own special function, there's no error checking or validation. And if it's your own special function, please don't name it the same as the standard function. Oh, and remember that C allows multi-digit precision.

Comment: Regarding things like `if (str[i + 2] >= '0' && str[i + 2] <= '9')`, better use the standard [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
case '.':
            if (str[i + 2] >= '0' && str[i + 2] <= '9')
            {
                print_double2(va_arg(args, double), str[i + 2]);
```

You are printing on dot. You have to print on `'f'`, dot only specifies that *the next number* means precision. I recommend having state, where you store if you have seen a dot, and seen precision, and then pass all the state to printers. You can keep the state in the execution flow (take different path when noticed a dot), but the number of different state combinations is so big it will become unreadable. Consider:

```
struct state {
    bool seen_dot;
    bool seen_precision;
    int precision;
    /* TODO: hash, zero, field width, h,l,L,z,t,j modifiers, hex or octal modifiers, etc. */
};
```

Then when parsing you fill the state as characters come and act differently depending on current parsing state:

```
struct state state = {0};
for (..) {
   char c = str[....];
   switch (c) {
      case '.':
         if (state.seen_dot) {
              /* already seen a dot - error? ignore? up to you */
         }
         state.seen_dot = true;
         break;
      case 0: case 1: case 2: etc..
         if (state.seen_dot) {
             state.seen_precision = true;
             state.precision *= 10;
             state.precision += c - '0';
         } else {
             /* handle field width */
         }
         break;
      case 'f':
         print_double(state, va_arg(double));
         break;
     }
}
```

and then when printing, you have to take all options into account:

```
void print_double(struct state state, double var) {
   // default precision is 6 for floating point numbers
   int precision = state.seen_precision ? state.precision : 6;
   // print with precision digits after comma
   // handle field width. Handle FfAaGgEe all differently
}
```

Implementing your own printf especially floating point printing is *very* hard task. Specifically for floating point, you might want to read the good old https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/gcl-devel/2012-10/pdfkieTlklRzN.pdf and learn standard math.h headers https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/modf and research https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 .

Also, there are endless user implementations of printf on github that you can take inspiration from.

Answer (score 0):

> I really don't know what to do,

**Save time and enable all warnings**

Everything after this is minor stuff.  Enable all warnings.

---

**Type mis-match**

The below is bad code as `atoi()` expects a pointer to a *string* yet code provided a `char`.

```
void print_double2(int num, char cprecision) {
int precision = atoi(cprecision);  // Bad
```

**Wrong type**

`print_double2(va_arg(args, double), str[i + 2]);` sends a `doule` as the first agument, yet `void print_double2(int num, char cprecision)` expects an `int`.

`double fract_part = num - int_part;` is always 0 as `num` is an `int`.
It has no fraction.

**Overflow**

`int int_part = (int)num;` risks overflow if `num` was a `double`.  Research `modf()`.

**Weak approach**

The `while (fract_part > 0 && precision > 0)` attempts to print the fraction one digit at a time, yet does not attempt to *round* the result.

I'd expect the below to print "4.88" and not "4.87".

```
fprint("%.2f", 4.875);
```

Good rounding is difficult.  Do not break the number into whole and fraction parts as cases close to `xxx.999xxx` will fail.

The better approach depends on how good you want code to be - the edge cases are many.